# Negative reputation from a comment?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

I posted a comment on an answer yesterday (here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7433381/2057171 )
And today I got notification that my reputation had dropped by 1 because of that comment.... I'm just curious what happened that caused this haha, can you downvote comments? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Both of the other answers have a few downvotes. Did you downvote one of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It was because you downvoted the answer. Comments cannot ever affect your rep in any way.

Comment: Ahhhhh! Very neat! So if I down-vote an answer I take a damage of -1 rep? :)

Comment: Wait... I just realized, I never down-voted the answer haha...

Comment: @Albert Yes, but downvoting questions does not cost rep.

Comment: Ah! Turns out I down-voted a different answer on the same question :o)

Comment: Thankyou! I'll mark your answer as correct once the count-down timer runs out :)

Comment: Actually, comments can affect your rep if they trigger a serial downvoting spree (or a parallel downvoting spree, which is somewhat more legitimate)

Comment: As a side bit, don't think of it as "damage of -1 rep" but rather "spending one rep to further improve the quality of the site."  If at some point in the future, that answer is deleted you will recover your investment.

Comment: @Doorknob of Snow Yes and unfortunately, good  comments do not GAIN any rep either. This is annoying me most, since what is the point of UPvoting a *comment* if it doesn't affect anyone's rep in any way? It's pointless IMHO (to say the least).